# Regular expression for a number range with decimal point

Tags: android, regex, numbers, decimal

I want to write regular expression for a number range with one decimal point.
ex-number range is 70 to 98 with only one decimal point is allowed.
valid:
70.1
97.3
85

Invalid:
70.256
53
65.2000

Please help me. I am new with regular expressions. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hi! Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How to ask). In the meantime you should show what you allready acheived.

Answer (score 1):

Number ranges are tricky with regular expressions since you cannot say "between A and B". Instead you have to do everything character based. This is how you say from 70 to 98:

```
([7-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])
```

This is saying that if the number starts with 7 or 8 then the second digit can be any digit. If it start  with a 9 then the second digit can be between 0 and 8. This get trickier with longer digits.

In order to say that one decimal point is allowed as well do this:

```
(([7-8][0-9])|(9[0-8]))(\.[0-9])?
```

Here we added an optional "dot followed by any digit" to the end which may or may not be present due to the question mark after it.

Comment: It is working..-Thank you so much..but i can't do it for single digit..ex. for a range 8 to 36

Comment: ([8-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-6])\.[0-9]?   aa have tried this..bus this is not working...plz help me..

Comment: What is not working? If you want to do it for 8 to 36 use this:
([8-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-6])